# Pass variable to installanywhere command line build.exe

Tags: installation, installanywhere

how can I pass a command line argument to build.exe to specify where is the source folder to be included in the installer?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From IA help:

> Add an environment variable for the source path, prepended with `IA_PATH_` tag. For example, to set the source path `SOURCE_PATH`, set the environment variable `IA_PATH_SOURCE_PATH`.